# error passing a matrix with const pointer and const values to a function using eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, constants

I have a function that is declared as follows:

```
int myFunc(int const (* const p_Matrix)[5][5]);
```

I pass a pointer to a matrix to the function, the pointer is const and it points to const data

when I call it I do the following:

```
int X = 0;
int Matrix[5][5];
// fill Matrix with some values
X = myFunc(&Matrix);
```

the problem is that I get the following warning when I compile:

> note: expected 'const int (* const)[5][5]' but argument is of type
>   'int (*)[5][5]'

This warning I only get when I use eclipse, however I dont get it using visual studio 2017

I dont have much understanding of the mechanics of how a compiler works, but I am pretty sure my syntax is correct.

Can someone please explain what the problem is and how I can get rid of the warning.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT: 
when I removed the first const, the warning is gone. I don't know the reason behind it though.**

Comment: AFAIK, eclipse is not a compiler, thus which compiler do you use?

Comment: You want to drop the 2nd `const`.

Comment: I found that when I drop the first const the problem is gone, when I drop the 2nd one alone the warning still exists

Comment: gcc says: _pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]_. I personally find it a bit overly pessimistic. A pointer to writeable data is passed to a function which promises to read but not write. (This might be simply for strictness or for a very intricated reason.) [Tested on Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EPuhyX)